# Python multiprocessing.cpu_count() returns '1' on 4-core Nvidia Jetson TK1

Tags: python, cpu, python-multiprocessing

Can anyone tell me why Python's `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` function would return `1` when called on a Jetson TK1 with four ARMv7 processors?

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> multiprocessing.cpu_count()
1
```

The Jetson TK1 board is more or less straight out of the box, and no one has messed with cpusets. From within the same Python shell I can print the contents of `/proc/self/status` and it tells me that the process should have access to all four cores:

```
>>> print open('/proc/self/status').read()
----- (snip) -----
Cpus_allowed:   f
Cpus_allowed_list:      0-3
----- (snip) -----
```

What else could be causing this behavior from `cpu_count()`?

### Edit:

To test Klaus's hypothesis, I used the following code to run a very simple experiment:

```
import multiprocessing

def f(x):
    n = 0
    for i in xrange(10000):
        n = max(n, multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    return n

p = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
for i in range(10):
    print p.map(f, [1,2,3,4,5])
```

Which produced the following output:

```
[3, 3, 3, 3, 1]
[4, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[4, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[3, 3, 4, 3, 3]
[4, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[3, 3, 4, 3, 3]
[4, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[3, 3, 4, 3, 3]
[3, 3, 3, 4, 3]
[4, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Running just a single iteration of `p.map(f, [1,2,3,4,5])` usually produces `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`, although occasionally a `2` will appear as one of the list elements.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

On Linux systems `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` relies on a `sysconf (_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN)` call, which returns the number of *online* CPUs in contrast to `sysconf (_SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF)` which returns the number of *configured* CPUs.

The values might differ in systems with advanced CPU power management functionality that sets CPU cores offline to save energy or with similar dynamic CPU activation functionality.

Comment: Interesting. An idiom I see a lot is using the return-value of `cpu_count()` to initialize the number of processes in a `Pool`. This kind of "dynamic CPU activation" strategy, which the TK1 seems to employ, breaks that idiom rather badly on a quiescent system. Is there some straightforward (and portable) way to get at the number of *usable* processors (as opposed the number in use) from Python?

Comment: Created a separate question -- http://stackoverflow.com/q/31346974/1337498 -- about detecting the number of usable processors from Python.

Comment: It might not be the most beautiful solution, but you could monkey-patch `cpu_count()` to return the number from an other source.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation for os.cpu_count() (which declares that it returns the total number of CPUS, not the number of usable CPUs) provides a means to count usable CPUs:

```
len(os.sched_getaffinity(0))
```

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.cpu_count

Comment: Indeed, though in Python 2.x, `cpu_count()` seemed to return the number of _online_ CPUs, per the accepted answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31347858/1337498, in which I asked the question in terms of _usable_ CPUs, and got essentially the same answer as yours. (At the time I asked, I was kind of stuck using Python 2.7, and `os.sched_getaffinity()` was only available from Python 3.3 and above.)