# Portable way of detecting number of *usable* CPUs in Python

Tags: python, cpu

Per this question and answer -- [Python multiprocessing.cpu_count() returns '1' on 4-core Nvidia Jetson TK1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31344582/1337498) --  the output of Python's `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` function on certain systems reflects the number of CPUs actively *in use*, as opposed to the number of CPUs actually *usable* by the calling Python program.

A common Python idiom is to use the return-value of `cpu_count()` to initialize the number of processes in a `Pool`. However, on systems that use such a "dynamic CPU activation" strategy, that idiom breaks rather badly (at least on a relatively quiescent system).

Is there some straightforward (and portable) way to get at the number of **usable** processors (as opposed the number *currently in use*) from Python?

**Notes:**

1. This question is not answered by the accepted answer to [How to find out the number of CPUs using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006289/how-to-find-out-the-number-of-cpus-using-python), since as noted in the question linked at the top of *this* question, printing the contents of `/proc/self/status` shows all 4 cores as being available to the program.
2. To my mind, "portable" excludes any approach that involves parsing the contents of `/proc/self/status`, whose format may vary from release to release of Linux, and which doesn`t even exist on OS X. (The same goes for any other pseudo-file, as well.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think you will get any truly portable answers, so I will give a correct one.

The correct<sup>*</sup> answer for Linux is `len(os.sched_getaffinity(pid))`, where `pid` may be `0` for the current process. This function is exposed in Python 3.3 and later; if you need it in earlier, you'll have to do some fancy `cffi` coding.

Edit: you might try to see if you can use a function `int omp_get_num_procs();` if it exists, it is the only meaningful answer I found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150355/programmatically-find-the-number-of-cores-on-a-machine) but I haven't tried it from Python.

Comment: Dang, sucks for me, I'm using Python 2.7. :-) Punting for now (got real deliverables, ya know?), but eventually I may dig into the `cffi` and this gives me a good case to try.

Answer (score 8):

Use psutil:

from the doc https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/:

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.cpu_count()
4
>>> psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)  # Ignoring virtual cores
2
```

This is portable

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that gets the number of available CPU cores for the current process on systems that implement [`sched_getaffinity`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html), and Windows:

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes
import os
from platform import system


def num_available_cores() -> int:
    if hasattr(os, 'sched_getaffinity'):
        return len(os.sched_getaffinity(0))
    elif system() == 'Windows':
        kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32')
        DWORD_PTR = ctypes.wintypes.WPARAM
        PDWORD_PTR = ctypes.POINTER(DWORD_PTR)
        GetCurrentProcess = kernel32.GetCurrentProcess
        GetCurrentProcess.restype = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE
        GetProcessAffinityMask = kernel32.GetProcessAffinityMask
        GetProcessAffinityMask.argtypes = (ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE, PDWORD_PTR, PDWORD_PTR)
        mask = DWORD_PTR()
        if not GetProcessAffinityMask(GetCurrentProcess(), ctypes.byref(mask), ctypes.byref(DWORD_PTR())):
            raise Exception("Call to 'GetProcessAffinityMask' failed")
        return bin(mask.value).count('1')
    else:
        raise Exception('Cannot determine the number of available cores')
```

On Linux and any other systems that implement [`sched_getaffinity`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html), we use Python's built-in wrapper for it.

On Windows we use [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) to call [`GetProcessAffinityMask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprocessaffinitymask).

As far as I know there are no user APIs or tools to get/set the CPU affinity on macOS. In most cases `os.cpu_count()` will work fine, but if you truly need the number of *available* cores you may be out of luck.