# Portable way to find the number of processors/CPU's in a shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, sh

Since it's common to write shell scripts which pass the number of jobs to a command, I'm interested to know what a good, portable way is to get the number of processors on mainstream * Unix systems.

Something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31344582) but not depending on Python.

---

* *By mainstream, I mean that will work on popular Unix system used in production today (Linux/BSD's/Darwin? But the more portable the better).*

Comment: Define "portable"? Define "mainstream?" Does SCO UNIX count? Does AIX? Does Ubuntu on Windows? If you're going for just Linux and BSD you can probably do it. For everything else the answer is *maybe*.

Comment: "maybe others" is not a very specific definition. These systems can vary wildly. The POSIX standard does not require any particular way of getting this information.

Comment: Good point, general case is - I release a POSIX shell script which is written to be portable, I want people on Unix systems *(which I don't use)* to be able to use this without running into problems.

Comment: I think you're far more likely to find one of these things than you ever are to successfully write one. Testing it will be an exercise in frustration if you don't have access to these systems in advance.

Comment: *"find one of these things"* ?

Comment: Yes, a script that does this particular thing.

Comment: Surely this can be done in ~8 lines of shell or less? not sure this should require a separate tool, especially since there is overlap between how its done on different systems.

Comment: If you think that you really have no idea what you're getting into. For Linux and BSD and possibly BSD-derived OSes like macOS/Darwin, sure. For other things like Solaris, HP-UX, AIX you may be left adding in hacks upon hacks. If you've ever dared to look inside a typical `configure` script that should give you an idea of the horrors that await.

Comment: The question is not asking about the other Unix's you mention (that is of course a can of worms).

Comment: Be specific, please. If you want *just* Linux, FreeBSD and macOS then that's probably achievable, but still, this is border-line off-topic as it stands.

Comment: @tadman, this is spesific, there are only ~3 mainstream BSD's (even if you want to include the forks) - they all use the same command to get the number of CPU's, so the command for FreeBSD will work on DragonFly or something more esoteric too.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there are peculiar things that might need to be considered (in rare cases, I admit): Firstly, amongst the CPUs that the hardware is equipped with, some of them may be put offline (e.g. I had to do that after a fan broke). Secondly, a user process may be granted or revoked the use of some particular CPUs. These are mostly questions that occur on big servers, not on home PCs

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a *fairly* portable function to get the number of processors that works in `sh`, `bash` and compatible shells:

- Uses `nproc` on Linux.
- Use `getconf` as a fallback, it's and part of coreutils.
- Tested to work on:
- `Linux`
- `Darwin` (macOS)
- `FreeBSD`, `NetBSD`, `OpenBSD`

*... probably others, feel free to test :)*

Feel free to suggest additions:

```
#!/bin/sh
portable_nproc() {
    OS="$(uname -s)"
    if [ "$OS" = "Linux" ]; then
        NPROCS="$(nproc --all)"
    elif [ "$OS" = "Darwin" ] || \
         [ "$(echo "$OS" | grep -q BSD)" = "BSD" ]; then
        NPROCS="$(sysctl -n hw.ncpu)"
    else
        NPROCS="$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)"  # glibc/coreutils fallback
    fi
    echo "$NPROCS"
}

# test
portable_nproc
```

---

A more terse command that covers many systems is to check `getconf` for glibc, then `sysctl` for BSD family of Unixes: eg:

```
getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN 2>/dev/null || sysctl -n hw.ncpu
```

I have a slight preference for checking each platform since it allows others to be added more easily, but in practice the single line works in many cases.

Comment: Well... there is no `[[...]]` in POSIX shell. Likewise there is no `<<< $OS` (herestring) -- both are bashisms. `-eq` expects a *numeric* argument (`=` is what you want). I don't have a `"Darwin"` box to check, so I'll have to take you at face value on the `sed` expression `:)`

Comment: Removed bashisums

Comment: Much better. Good luck with your scripting. If you haven't used [**ShellCheck.net**](http://www.shellcheck.net/) before -- it is a great resource.

Comment: `echo "$OS" | grep -q "BSD"` is a little cleaner; `expr "$OS" : ".*BSD" > /dev/null` is more efficient--for some very small value of "more", anyway :)

Comment: @chepner - the sed command is checking the string ends with BSD, nevertheless this is posix compliant, so a bit cleaner.

Comment: @ideasman42 Regular expressions are not implicitly anchored; the `sed` command (just like `grep`) would have to use `BSD$` to check if the string *ends* with BSD. (Note that the regular expression argument to `expr` *is* anchored to the beginning of the string, which is why it needs to start with `.*`, unlike with `grep` or `sed`.)

Answer (score 8):

I'll throw in my one-liner heavily influenced by [ideasman42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45181694/1905491)'s answer above:

```
nproc 2>/dev/null || sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu 2>/dev/null || getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Great! My one-liner to define `MAKE`: `export MAKE="make -j$(nproc || sysctl -n hw.ncpu || getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN || echo 1)" 2>/dev/null
`

Answer (score 3):

Use nproc which is part of coreutils, so it should be available on most Linux installs.

Command nproc prints the number of processing units available to the current process, which may be less than the number of online processors.

To find the number of all installed cores/processors use nproc --all

```
$ nproc --all
4
```

or a more portable one will be sysctl with /proc/cpuinfo combined

sysctl should work on darwin /BSD

```
grep -c '^processor' /proc/cpuinfo 2>/dev/null || sysctl -n hw.ncpu
```

Comment: It doesn't work on macOS. On macOS you can use `sysctl -n hw.ncpu`.

Comment: This is not accurate. On my system, Ryzen 5 3600, `nproc --all` reports 32 but this CPU only has 6 cores (12 threads) which is still 20 shy of the number reported by nproc.