# Linux CPU string by Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I try to build a string that identifies my CPU.

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep "model name"

model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
```

What I want is the string just once and the number of cores.

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz - 8 Cores
```

How can I get this with bash/awk/sed the best way?

Otherways I would do it with perl but I think it should work with piping too.

Comment: It's not quite the format, but piping the result into `uniq -c` will at least give you all the desired information.

Comment: Note that `/cpu/procinfo` is not portable e.g. doesn't work in macOS. See [Portable way to find the number of processors/CPU's in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45181115/5291015)

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Shouldn't we sort the lines first? `uniq` relies on sorted lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could let [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) count the matching lines and append that to the result:

```
awk -F ': ' \
    '/model name/ {cpu=$2; count++} END {print cpu " - " count " Cores"}' \
/proc/cpuinfo
```

---

Outputs the following on my (ancient) machine:

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X3430  @ 2.40GHz - 4 Cores
```

---

`AWK` can read directly from the file, so I've removed the [useless `cat` call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat).

Comment: Indeed the simplest solution if only one CPU is present

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU `awk`:

```bash
$ awk -F': ' '/^model name/ {models[$2]++} END {for (i in models) printf "%s - %s Cores\n", i, models[i]}' /proc/cpuinfo
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz - 8 Cores
```

this solution builds an array where the key is the model name, and the value is the count.

Answer (score 1):

Can use `uniq` as commented above and then pass to `sed` for formatting :

```
grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo \
| uniq -c \
| sed -E 's/[[:space:]]+ ([[:digit:]]+) model name[[:space:]]+: (.+)$/\2 - \1 Cores/g'
```

uniq gets the count which is then matched by sed with `([[:digit:]]+)` and moved to the end of the string as per your format

**with output**

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz - 8 Cores
```