# How to detect number of total cores available in a multi-cpu sytem?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to do multiprocessing using Python. I have access to 4 x 24Core CPUs.

When I try and detect the amount of CPU using code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
mp.cpu_count()
```

It returns 4 rather than 96, is there any way of making Python detect all 96 cores?

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31344582/python-multiprocessing-cpu-count-returns-1-on-4-core-nvidia-jetson-tk1 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346974/portable-way-of-detecting-number-of-usable-cpus-in-python help? If not it probably makes sense if you show how your system is set up.

Comment: also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006289/how-to-find-out-the-number-of-cpus-using-python

Answer (score 0):

For python, you can use directly `psutil`, it is general lib for CPU. I can get the core directly through `psutil.cpu_count()`. That is the same core I got through `htop`

Comment: Hi @dtlam26, this method is still only showing 4 rather than 96.

Comment: can you show me your `lscpu` if you are on linux?