# Mutual list in multiple processes

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

Let's say that I have an empty list `my_list` and 5 processes `pr1, pr2, pr3, pr4, pr5`, where each of them appends something to my list.

My question is : Is something like this possible? And will it behave normaly or an error will occur?

Comment: because each process has own memory, i think is impossible. you should use Queue for this operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all 5 of your processes applying the same function, but to different inputs? If this is the case, then using `Pool.map()` from `multiprocessing` is appropriate:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

n_processes = 5 #number of processes to use
input = [0.,1.,2.,3.] #some input

def f(x):
    #the function being applied on each thread
    return x**2. #for example

p = Pool(n_processes)
my_list = p.map(f,input)
p.close() #close the pool now you're finished with it
```

So the function f(x) is being applied to different inputs on each process, and then the output is collected in a list (equivalent to your 'my_list' that was empty to begin with). The output array is ordered in the same way as the input array i.e. if `input = [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5]` then `output=[f(x1),f(x2),f(x3),f(x4),f(x5)]`.

Comment: And after I'm done with done, am I suppose to close them/ do anything with them ?

Comment: Sorry yes, once you're finished you would write `p.close()`.

Comment: I do not know why, but whenever I run your program, my computer freezes. Could you look into it, please?

Comment: I don't find the same problem, it works fine on my machine. Try changing `n_processes=1` and `n_processes=2` and see if it works in those cases.

Comment: For `n_processes=1 /2` it works for me as well. I do not know ...
But thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Maybe [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039659/python-multiprocessings-pool-process-limit)  will help explain the issues you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

If these processes are independent then something like this is not possible. At least not without some additional mechanisms like sockets (which greatly increases complexity).

If these are created via `multiprocessing` and `my_list` is just a list then each process will have its own copy of the list.

Again in `multiprocessing` if you define `my_list` as `multiprocessing.Queue` then indeed this will be a shared structure between processes.

Comment: But if my processes will return each a list, then I could concatenate all of them in the list I need, right?

Comment: @SnuKies Normally a process doesn't return anything. It just ends its execution. However Python does give a neat abstraction that allows that. Are you talking about `multiprocessing.map`? I'm not sure, try it.

Comment: I'm really new to `multiprocessing`.
Currently I am working to a project where I'm installing multiple components using `multiprocessing` and I thought I could use `multiprocessing` to determine which of those components have changed since last time I installed them and which have not.