# Process goes in infinite wait, if increasing number of processes

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, queue, python-multiprocessing

I am completely new to python multiprocessing. I am trying to implement the process in my code. The code runs fine for a limited number of processes. But as I increase the number of processes, then the process goes into an infinite loop.

Basically, I am trying to parallelize the square function, and storing the value in the array. The functions return the values via queues.

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue
import time
import numpy as np
import os


def print_square(num,pos,a,que1):
    """
    function to print square of given num
    """
    a[pos] = num * num

    que1.put((pos,a))

    return




if __name__ == "__main__":

    # number of process
    NP=int(100)

    # creating thread
    p=[]
    num = 2

    a = np.zeros(NP)
    que1 = Queue()
    for i in range (NP):

        p1 = Process(target=print_square, args=(num,i,a,que1))
        # q.append(que1)
        num = num + 1
        p.append(p1)


    print('process created')

    start_time=time.time()
    # starting processes

    for process in p:
        print('cr - i', process)
        process.start()

    print('procesS started')

    for process in p:
        print('join',process,time.time()-start_time)
        process.join()
        process.terminate()

    result = []
    print('result started')
    for process in p:
        print(process)
        result.append(que1.get(block=False))
    print('result completed')
    # result.sort()

    result1 = [r[1] for r in result]

    for i in range(len(result1)):
        a[i] = result1[i][i]


    a1 = time.time()-start_time
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you are hitting a machine/OS limitation. For example, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039659/python-multiprocessings-pool-process-limit). How many cores do you have on your machine? I doubt it is anywhere close to `100` and therefore it is unlikely that you would need to spawn off that many processes.

Comment: I have 24 processors. I need to spawn that many processes. However, I figured out the problem. The actual problem was: I was joining process before getting the queue, this was causing the problem and putting it into the deadlock. I appreciate your response. Thank you..!!