# Can one use multiprocess.Process within another multiprocess.Process one with and one without join?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

Have a look at this problem, where I wish `func2` to be run in the background. In `func2` I spawn multiple processes and each of the processes output some data, that at the end are joined. I am not calling `func2` directly, but calls `func1` WITHOUT join. My intension is for this code to be used in a web application setting, where a user uploads a task to the backend. I will then call `func1` that initiates `func2` without waiting for `func2` to complete. My problem is, as soon as `func1` has ended, then all `func2` processes are dead before reaching completion. The problem is much more severe if I change `range` in func2 into a large number say 1000.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import json

class Test:
    def func1(self):
        p = Process(target = self.func2)
        p.start()
        #Note I do not call join here because I want func2 to be executed in the background. It seems as soon as p.start() 
        #is complete all threads processes spawned by func2 are dead before they complete 
    
    def func2(self):
        queue = Queue()
        
        queueList = list()
        jobList = list()
        responseList = list()
        for i in range(1000):
            p = Process(target = self.work, args = (i, queue))
            p.start()
            jobList.append(p)
            queueList.append(queue)
        
        for q in queueList:
            responseList.append(q.get())
        
        for p in jobList:
            p.join()
            
        #Do some other stuff with the data
        signalPath = 'path_to_somewhere/testProcess.json'
        
        with open(signalPath, 'w') as fileHandle:
            json.dump(responseList, fileHandle)
    
    def work(self, i, queue):
        print(i)
        queue.put(i)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    classObj = Test()
    classObj.func1()
```

Comment: create a global empty list, say `l`. Then inside `startTask`, after you have started `p`, do `l.append(p)`

Comment: I am not sure that it solves this issue. I have reexplained the problem, making it easier to read.

Comment: I see, I could not reproduce your issue through the code you put here. This shouldn't be happening either because all processes spawned through the `Process` class are non-daemonic by default, and the main needs to wait for all of them to complete. Can you confirm that the above code does reproduce the issue you described and not wait for all subprocesses to complete? What python version and os are you running it on?

Comment: I am not sure what benefit comes from creating more Processes than CPU cores.  A Process is an OS resource and so Process creation is fairly expensive.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039659/python-multiprocessings-pool-process-limit.  In any case, your program runs without error on Win10, Py3.11. Why do you think that "all the processes are dead," and what is "much more severe" when the Process count is 1000?